# Hub commands returning a 401

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh, key

I'm trying to set up Github on my new laptop. I've created a new project locally, then SSH key.

Hub create:

- with username and password: 401 (bad credentials. The API can't be accessed using username/password authentication. Please create a personal access token)
- with token: 401 (unauthorized)

So I manually created the repo on GitHub.
I can push to it no problem, my remotes are there, but when I try to `hub browse`, I still get a 401.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

username and password are for HTTPS URL.
Creating an SSH key would be ignored in that case.

So make sure to try and create a repo using [`gh` (`cli.github.com`)](https://cli.github.com/), not `hub` (obsolete).

- First [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) (use a token)
- Then [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create)